# android fragment destroyed after home or overview buttons are pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm fairly new to android programming, so please bear with me. I've tried searching all over SO, tutorialspoint, big nerd ranch, etc, but I'm not finding/understanding this: how do I make a fragment persist after a user has pressed the home or overview buttons? For example:

I have two fragments A and B in an activity with a toggle button to switch between the two fragments. By default, fragment A loads on the screen when the activity is created. If I toggle to fragment B and press either home or overview and then return to the app, fragment A is displayed. I understand why it's displaying, but what I don't understand is how to keep fragment B displayed.

I've read about the backstack, savedInstanceState, and setRetainInstance (among several others), but haven't been able to figure it out.

I'm overriding `onAttach(Context context)`, `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState)`, and `onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)` in both fragments, and `onStart()` and `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` in my activity.

fragments:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    faContext = (FragmentActivity) context;

    super.onAttach(context);
}// end onAttach(Activity activity)


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

    if(bundle != null) {
        String bundleAdminId = getString(R.string.bundle_admin_name);
        adminName = bundle.getString(bundleAdminId);
    }
    else {
        Log.d("BUNDLE_Profile", "bundle is null");
    }

    // Defines the xml file for the fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, parent, false);
}// end onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

`onViewCreated` only has button event handlers

activity:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // start the home fragment
    createFragment(new HomeFragment(), R.id.frag_container);

    // update the local storage
}// end onStart()


private void createFragment(Fragment fragment, int fragContainerId) {
    // make sure the passed fragment isn't null
    if(fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = faContext.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(fragContainerId, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}// end createFragment(Fragment fragment)`
```

`onCreate` also has button handlers

Comment: why don't you create your fragments in the OnCreate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot retain the fragment position when re-launching app unless it is stored. So one way could be while switching between the fragments, store the current position of fragment in Shared Preference.While restarting the application read the previously stored fragment position and update SharedPreferences value when switched.

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("fragmentPosition",MODE_PRIVATE);

            if(sharedPreferences.getInt("position",0)==1) loadFragmentOne();
            else loadFragmentTwo();
       }

       public void onToggleMethod(){

           if(currentToggle ==1){
              LoadFragmentTwo();
              UpdateSharedPreference();
           }
           else{
              loadFragmentOne();
              UpdateSharedPreference();
           }
      }
```

Comment: Even if the app hasnt fully exited?

Comment: Yes... It lasts until you clear shared preferences data or you clear the app data

Answer (score 2):

Use tags to open a fragment.Try this function

```
public void openNewFragment(Fragment f, String tag) {

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    {
        if (fragment != null) {
            if (currentFragment != null) {
                if (fragment.getClass().equals(currentFragment.getClass())) {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return;
                }
            }
            ft.show(fragment);
            ft.hide(currentFragment);
            currentFragment = fragment;
        } else {
            if (currentFragment != null)
                ft.hide(currentFragment);
            ft.add(R.id.container, f, tag);
            currentFragment = f;
        }
        ft.commit();


    }
}
```

In this function you have to provide fragment name and its tag.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the activity goes to the stopped mode and getting started when you return back to the activity from home after some time. May be because of the resources are freed from the memory.

To know more better on this just try to be on fragment b and immediately make the home press and again come back to app through the recent apps section and see the behavior.

Also if the problem is what i have stated above then.. try following

1. Try creating a variable that is static and try to remember the last loaded fragment and in the on resume of the activity load the fragment which was last loaded.
2. Else in the onstart load the fragment the using the fragment manager with a tag and also put a condition before the loading to check whether the fragment is alredy in memory if so dont load anything.

Something like this..
    `onStart(){
      if(fragmentManager.getFragmentByTag("String tag")== null){
      createFragment();
       }
     }`

Try and let me know if this is useful.

Comment: to properly format code use `{}` button or indent with 4 spaces

Comment: Very useful information! Unfortunately it wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Change the onStart method like this ,

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // start the home fragment

        if(faContext.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_container) == null) {
            createFragment(new HomeFragment(), R.id.frag_container);
        }

        // update the local storage
    }// end onStart()
```